# Bad rendering of bounty custom message dialog

Tags: bug, design

I just posted a bounty on [one of my questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9745/gamification-in-asian-classrooms) and I noticed that the rendering is off. The vertical lines on the far left (where it says "Enter a custom message" the E does not have the vertical line, just the three horizontal lines). This is true of all the text on the far left side.

I'm guessing that since not that many bounties get awarded this has not been been caught.

In case someone wants to reproduce this, I'm using FireFox Portable 20.0.1 on Win7 x64.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I don't think I see what you're seeing.

Comment: Also, posting this here is fine... I can let one of the main devs know if necessary.

Comment: @eykanal I've posted a screenshot above.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on win or osx, FF20. here's my [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/dm3rKCI.png). Can anyone else reproduce this bug?

Comment: I've reproduced this on Firefox 20.0.1 on Win 8, @Jin. The trick is, you have to type a message into the box - when you hit the end of the first line, just before the message wraps, it'll scroll the entire contents of the dialog to the left slightly. It won't show up until you type a message in (although the right border of the entryfield appears cut off until you click in it), and it won't show up if you paste a long message in; you have to manually type more than 80 characters into the box.